# Mysql - it´s possible use Group By semester?

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I need to use a group by per semester in a query. Anyone know any way to do this?

If I use:

```
 `HAVING Date Between '2012-01 'and '2012-06'`
```

I believe it will work, but will not be the correct result for the query.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your full query and table schema's - having people randomly guess what they are is not going to help people answer your question. Oh and adding - also what you want your result set to look like is good too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this one -

```
+------+------------+
| id   | date       |
+------+------------+
| 1    | 2012-08-14 |
| 2    | 2012-09-20 |
| 3    | 2012-05-14 |
| 4    | 2012-05-08 |
| 5    | 2012-08-16 |
+------+------------+

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES 
  (1, '2012-08-14'),
  (2, '2012-09-20'),
  (3, '2012-05-14'),
  (4, '2012-05-08'),
  (5, '2012-08-16');

SELECT
  YEAR(date) year,
  IF(MONTH(date) < 7, 1, 2) semester,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  year, semester;

+------+----------+----------+
| year | semester | COUNT(*) |
+------+----------+----------+
| 2012 |        1 |        2 |
| 2012 |        2 |        3 |
+------+----------+----------+
```

Using HAVING clause -

```
SELECT
  YEAR(date) year,
  IF(MONTH(date) < 7, 1, 2) semester,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  year, semester
HAVING
  semester = 1

+------+----------+----------+
| year | semester | COUNT(*) |
+------+----------+----------+
| 2012 |        1 |        2 |
+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This query works to me, but if use a having clause, don´t works fine, return 0 results:
`SELECT
  YEAR(date) year,
  IF(MONTH(date) < 7, 1, 2) semester,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  year, semester
 HAVING semester = 1`

Comment: I try to do with `HAVING semester = 1`, but don´t works for me. I think this is weird, but it worked that way:  `HAVING semester < 2`    (first semester) Or `HAVING semester > 1`    (second semester) anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hm, it should work. I added INSERT statement to example. Try all example as is.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get any date semester with:

```
FLOOR( ( MONTH(date)-1) / 6 ) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem of getting only the first semester or second semester just as follows.

To get only first semester:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(date) year,
  IF(MONTH(date) < 7, 1, 2) semester,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table_name
WHERE 
  MONTH(date) NOT IN(7,8,9,10,11,12)    
GROUP BY
  year, semester;
```

Thanks to all that helped.